# Can i deploy a TURN (coturn) server on the same droplet as my Node web server?

Tags: deployment, hosting, digital-ocean, turn, coturn

I'm creating a video chat web app and I need to deploy a coturn TURN server somewhere. What I'm asking is do I need to purchase 2 droplets on Digital ocean, one for the TURN server and one for my web server or can I place them in the same droplet thus saving money.

Is there any good reason in buying 2 hosting spots, maybe performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can deploy it at the same server. But you shouldn't.
There will be a time when you need to upgrade the turn server, i.e. the numbers of users are increasing. If you split these applications, the node server will not be affected, since it's not necessary to upgrade it.

Another example would be, that you want to use more than 1 turn server, for load balancing for example. Also in case of a problem, once application will not be affected and it's easier to integrate a replacement / backup server.

My advice would be:

```
yourdomain.com -> Main application
turn1.yourdomain -> Turnserver
turnX.yourdomain -> maybe an additional server in the future.
```

With that solution you can also make sure, that the turn server is not using all the bandwidth, so yes, that's the possible performance issue you mentioned.